# Controlling input and output in c++ for printing a table while entering variables

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to create a "sudoku" table in C++ using arrays and I want it to be printed on the screen while I'm using `cin` for getting VARIABLES.
I could use the next lines but it will be 49 line result in command prompt but I wonder if there is a way that I can make it look like a table while I'm entering the variables?

```
void getsudokuin (int entry[9][9]){
for (int i=0;i<9;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<9;j++){
        cin >> entry[i][j];
        if (entry[i][j] <1 && entry[i][j]>9){
            entry[i][ j]=-1;
        }
        else if (entry[i][j]>0 && entry[i][j]<10){

        }
        else {
        entry[i][j]==-1;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean _"look like a table"_? Grid like input positions?

Comment: Are you asking how to accept input that is formatted like a table?  That should already work as expected; `cin` splits on any whitespace, so where you place spaces and newlines in the input are up to you.

Comment: What programming language are you using?  You say it's C++ in one place and C in another.

Comment: yes some input positions so when the user types a number and pushes enter it dont go to the next line but it pushes a tab or two spaces and waits for user to enter the other number

Comment: @DrewDormann I don't really know the diffrence at this stage my apologies

Comment: as `cin` and `cout` do not exist in `c`, removing tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a way to set the position of the screen cursor.

If you are running a windows console application, you can use [SetConsoleCursorPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition):

```
void SetCursorPos(int XPos, int YPos)
{
    COORD Coord;

    Coord.X = XPos;
    Coord.Y = YPos;

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Coord);
}
```

If you are running under Linux, you can use (for ANSI compatible terminal):

```
void SetCursorPos(int XPos, int YPos)
{
    printf("\033[%d;%dH", YPos+1, XPos+1);
}
```